# Efficient mechanism to determine if open file has been externally modified?

Tags: monitoring, open-files, system-calls

For example, the IDE I'm using at the moment (Aptana Studio) notifies me as soon as a file's contents it has open have been changed by some external program.

I can imagine having a periodic loop run stat() on a file and check the time of last data modification. Is this how it's normally done or is there a blocking interrupt-like mechanism used instead?

Comment: I think you are on the right track. Have a look at [http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_3.html#SEC36](http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_3.html#SEC36)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) system on Linux, or the [kqueue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) system on BSD/OSX, gives you an event-driven ("interrupt-like") mechanism to do this.